# simple operations with queues (I got 2 errors)

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

So I need to implement (static implementation) some operation with queues.I wrote a function for each operation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

void initQueue(Queue& Q)
{
    Q.head = Q.tail = 0;
}

void put(Queue& Q, Atom a) //enqueue function
{
    if (Q.tail >= DIMMAX)
    {
        cout << "The queue is full" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Q.vect[Q.tail] = a;
    Q.tail++;
}

Atom get(Queue& Q) //dequeue function
{
    if (isEmpty(Q))
    {
        cout << "The queue is empty" << endl;
        Atom a;
        return a;
    }
    Atom x = Q.vect[Q.head];
    Q.head++;
    return x;
}

Atom front(Queue& Q)
{
    if (isEmpty(Q))
    {
        cout << "The queue is empty" << endl;
        Atom a;
        return a;
    }
    return Q.vect[Q.head];
}

int isEmpty(Queue& Q)
{
    return (Q.head == Q.tail);
}
```

I got 2 errors in front and get function "uninitialized local variable 'a' used"
How to fix it and what I'm doing wrong?

The header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#define DIMMAX 8
typedef int Atom;
struct Queue {
    int head, tail;
    Atom vect[DIMMAX];
};
void initQueue(Queue& Q);
void put(Queue& Q, Atom a);
Atom get(Queue& Q);
Atom front(Queue& Q); 
int isEmpty(Queue& Q);

#endif
```

This is the header with the functions.

Comment: You declare `a` in `get(Queue&)`, but never set its value to anything. What are you returning when you `return a;`? A better question: what value do you want to return when the `Q` is empty?

Comment: Extending on @John 's comment, Are you sure you want to return anything when the queue is empty? This might be a decent time to get familiar with exceptions.

Comment: Well, 0, I think.However I think I should return nothing...

Comment: I may have been too obtuse above. The function must return a value or throw an exception. If you have values that are impossible to put in the queue, you can use one of them as a sentinel you can test for, but if all `int` values are possible your options are reduced to return something else, a proxy, that can have an impossible value to use as a sentinel or throw an exception. If getting from an empty queue is rare, it's is exceptional behaviour, you would throw an exception. If getting from an empty queue is common, consider a proxy.